# Snowflake/SQL Calculate distinct user Id count in trailing last 30 days for each date

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to get a daily count of distinct IDs in the last trailing 30 days.

The output should look like this:

```
DATE        Count(Distinct ID) Trailing Last 30D    Equation
2022-01-02  232                Distinct IDs in the last 30 days from 2022-01-02
2022-01-03  1231               [...]
2022-01-04  123 
2022-01-05  242 
2022-01-06  3432
```

However, from my query below - it does not return the correct distinct count of IDs from the last trailing 30 days. Can someone advise on how I should properly go about this? Is there a way to incorporate a window function to count the distinct count of IDs in the last trailing 30 days?

```
WITH DATE_SPINE AS (
    SELECT d.DATE
    FROM DATE d
    WHERE d.DATE BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-05-01'
)
SELECT d.DATE,
       COUNT(DISTINCT IFF(u.EVENT_DATE >= d.DATE - INTERVAL '30 DAYS', ID, NULL)) AS TRAILING_30_MAU
FROM DATE_SPINE D
LEFT JOIN USERS u ON u.EVENT_DATE = d.DATE
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join with a list of the dates between `the_date-29` and `the_date`, count:

```sql
with dates as (
    select distinct  o_orderdate a_date
    from SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1.ORDERS
)

select count(distinct o_custkey), a_date, count(distinct o_orderdate)
from SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1.ORDERS a
join dates b
on a.o_orderdate between b.a_date-29 and b.a_date
group by 2
order by 2
limit 100
```

[image]